# Interact With Google Assistant Via C#

Tags: c#, google-assistant-sdk

I'm currently creating a C# program to interact with Google Assistant and instead of how it currently operates:

1. Opens CMD Window
2. Press enter to send new request
3. Talk
4. Assistant answers you
5. Press enter to send new request

I want to be able to manually pass in the question of the user without talking, and I want to manually pull the assistant's request to text. How can I do this?

Pretty sure I have to use this: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha1

but I'm not sure how exactly to use it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending and receiving text isn't supported (yet). See the conversation at https://plus.google.com/101852559274654726533/posts/BskrFscRYdh and contribute your own use cases to get this higher on their internal issue tracker.

Comment: do you know if google has done something or if theres a workaround to do it? theres no update since last year on the conversation.

Comment: Yes, you can now send and receive text without having to use audio. See https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2#google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.AssistConfig. (If you have further questions about this - please post a new question on StackOverflow)